# Why is windowClosed not being called?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have an issue that why "windowClosed" method not being invoked in my test code as following,

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Tmp {

    class TFrame extends JFrame{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5729542298504858399L;

        public TFrame() {
            setTitle("title");
            setSize(300, 300);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TFrame t = new Tmp().new TFrame();
        t.addWindowStateListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowStateChanged(e);
                System.out.println(e.getOldState() + "<-old new->" + e.getNewState());
            }
        });
        t.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                System.out.println(e.getID() + "closed " + e.getNewState());
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                System.out.println(e.getID() + "closing" + e.getNewState());
            }
        });
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**If I write the statement setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE) or explicitly   call dispose() to TFrame, windowClosed() will get called.**

Is there anyone can explain it in more detail, I'm confusing what is the property way of writing listeners for windowClosed(), thanks in advance.

////////////////// updated according to some guides from Dan //////////////

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Tmp {

    class TFrame extends JFrame {
        // ignored .....
        t.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosed(e);
                System.out.println(e.getID() + "closed " + e.getNewState());
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                super.windowClosing(e);
                System.out.println(e.getID() + "closing" + e.getNewState());
                int quit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(t, "Are you sure to quit?");
                if(quit == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                    t.dispose();
                }
                else if (quit == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                    t.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });
        t.setVisible(true);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default value for `setDefaultCloseOperation` is `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`. With this, the window is not closed, it is only hidden.

Changing the value to something else, you get it to actually close rather than just hide it, so the event will be triggered.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I checked the setDefaultCloseOperation(..) in JFrame.java, it tells what you posted :-).  One more thing I'd like to bring up is that should I always use "DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE" as the parameter if I want windowClosed() to be called? It would be great if some nice and property guides/codes snippet be given.

Comment: It depends on the context. For instance, if you want to user to be asked something before closing, you must set it as DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE and on windowClosing display the question for the user and then dispose() the window.

Comment: I got that, I wrote a quick demo according to your suggestion, is it correct way of implementing? Please see the updated post :-)

Comment: It looks correct, excepting that you will probably not need the else part.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing, without the else part, the frame may not hidden, since I set the DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE as the parameter, right?

Comment: Right. If the user says he doesn't want to quit then you don't.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept it as the answer later, have a good day :D

Comment: I have to say, I'm not fond of the JRE's naming here. HIDE_ON_CLOSE implies that closing the window hides the window. Which is to say that you did close the window. Which is to say that you would normally expect windowClosed to be fired! It seems very obscure that only DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE would fire windowClosed. It's documented somewhere, but the naming is certainly ambiguous.